# get value from variable which contains xml

Tags: python, xml, jenkins

I have the next jenkins API script:

```
import jenkins
import json
import re

server = jenkins.Jenkins('https://jenkins_url', username, password)
nodes = json.dumps(server.get_nodes())
nodes = re.sub('\"offline\"|[:{} \[\]]|true,|false,|\"name\"|\"','',nodes).split(',')
for label in nodes:
    if label != 'master':
        print label
        node_config = server.get_node_config(label)
        print node_config
```

node_config contains for example the next xml text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slave>
  <name>test.server</name>
  <description></description>
  <remoteFS>/var/lib/jenkins</remoteFS>
  <numExecutors>1</numExecutors>
  <mode>EXCLUSIVE</mode>
  <retentionStrategy class="hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always"/>
  <launcher class="hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher" plugin="ssh-slaves@1.10">
    <host>test.server</host>
    <port>7777</port>
    <credentialsId>d0970a8f-d124</credentialsId>
    <maxNumRetries>0</maxNumRetries>
    <retryWaitTime>0</retryWaitTime>
  </launcher>
  <label>BuildServer</label>
  <nodeProperties/>
  <userId>test</userId>
</slave>
```

I want to get value of each of  tag to obtain on output eg test.server etc.

Could you please help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xml_text = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slave>
  <name>test.server</name>
  <description></description>
  <remoteFS>/var/lib/jenkins</remoteFS>
  <numExecutors>1</numExecutors>
  <mode>EXCLUSIVE</mode>
  <retentionStrategy class="hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always"/>
  <launcher class="hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher" plugin="ssh-slaves@1.10">
    <host>test.server</host>
    <port>7777</port>
    <credentialsId>d0970a8f-d124</credentialsId>
    <maxNumRetries>0</maxNumRetries>
    <retryWaitTime>0</retryWaitTime>
  </launcher>
  <label>BuildServer</label>
  <nodeProperties/>
  <userId>test</userId>
</slave>
"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(xml_text)

# show only a particular tag
for name in root.findall('name'):
    print(name.text)

# show all children at first level
for child in root:
    print('%s: %s' % (child.tag, child.text))

# build a dict (will only get last of any duplicate tags, and no children)
slave = {child.tag: child.text for child in root}

# build a dict (will only get last of any duplicate tags)
def xml_todict(xml_node):
    dict_ = {}
    for child in xml_node:
        dict_[child.tag] = xml_todict(child)
    dict_.update(xml_node.attrib)
    if not dict_:
        return xml_node.text
    if xml_node.text and 'text' not in dict_:
        dict_['text'] = xml_node.text
    return dict_

slave = xml_todict(root)
```

Comment: It prints all besides: <host>test.server</host>
    <port>7777</port>
    <credentialsId>d0970a8f-d124</credentialsId>
    <maxNumRetries>0</maxNumRetries>
    <retryWaitTime>0</retryWaitTime>

Comment: I have already found mistake: instead of root.findall('name') I had to put  root.findall('.//host'). According to docs "//" selects all subelements, on all levels beneath the current element (search the entire subtree). For example, “.//egg” selects all “egg” elements in the entire tree etc. Thanks for help!